# How to customize when jquery mobile dialog shows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I need to be able to choose when the jquery dialog opens up but nothing i seem to do works.

so far ive tried this

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- Include meta tag to ensure proper rendering and touch zooming -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Include jQuery Mobile stylesheets -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">

    <!-- Include the jQuery library -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Include the jQuery Mobile library -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">

            <a href="#myPopupDialog" data-rel="popup" data-role="dialog" data-position-to="window" data-transition="fade" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline">Open Dialog Popup</a>

            <a href="#" onclick="test()">Test</a>

            <div data-role="popup" id="myPopupDialog">

                <div data-role="header">
                    <h1>But wait theres more!</h1>
                </div>

                <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
                    <h2 style="text-align: center;">Would you like an exclusive offer?</h2>
                    <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all" data-rel="back">Sounds Good!</a>
                    <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-icon-back" data-rel="back" data-theme="a">No Thanks, Take me back..</a>
                </div>

                <div data-role="footer">
                    <h1>Footer Text</h1>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function(){

        console.log(document.body.scrollTop);

        if(document.body.scrollTop === 0)
        {
            $.mobile.changePage('#myPopupDialog', 'pop', true, true);
        }

    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

which works but when i change the if statement in the javascript it breaks also if i remove the anchor tag at the top it just doesnt show... jQuery mobile has me confused.

So anyway my question is how do manually make a dialog box show on the page, i would prefer it to show on the same page and not another page.

Comment: Sorry if anything is missing please leave a comment requesting what you need and ill provide it

Comment: `$("#myPopupDialog").popup("open")` not `$.mobile.changePage('#myPopupDialog'....` dialogs and popups aren't the same. Please refer to jQM docs.

Answer (score -1):

use this:

```
$("#myPopupDialog").addClass("ui-page-active ui-page ui-page-theme-a")
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: Either way this didnt work for me, i found a fix and will add my solution when i get the time